# Redis Clustering Waiting for the cluster to join Private VPC

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I have 3 EC2 Instances with Redis Running like this:

- Server 001: 10.0.1.203, Port: 6379
- Server 002: 10.0.1.202, Port: 6380
- Server 003: 10.0.1.190, Port: 6381

Config file for each one:

```
# bind 127.0.0.1
protected-mode no
port PORT
pidfile /var/run/redis_PORT.pid
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-PORT.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000
```

I can connect via redis to each one on each server.

But when I run the cluster creation the script never ends on Server 001.

```
root@ip-10-0-1-203:~/redis-stable# redis-cli --cluster create 10.0.1.203:6379 10.0.1.202:6380 10.0.1.190:6381
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 3 nodes...
Master[0] -> Slots 0 - 5460
Master[1] -> Slots 5461 - 10922
Master[2] -> Slots 10923 - 16383
M: 4c0b7609e5d906ff58d67ab446bbd9e20833e0db 10.0.1.203:6379
   slots:[0-5460] (5461 slots) master
M: a5dbd72815a1875b58a0cc0fd6a52dc0b76735b7 10.0.1.202:6380
   slots:[5461-10922] (5462 slots) master
M: 14d39c0876a982cadd50f301a3d35715171279c0 10.0.1.190:6381
   slots:[10923-16383] (5461 slots) master
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
>>> Nodes configuration updated
>>> Assign a different config epoch to each node
>>> Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster
Waiting for the cluster to join
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Server 002 logs:

```
44119:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:03.477 * Ready to accept connections
44119:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:45.362 # configEpoch set to 0 via CLUSTER RESET HARD
44119:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:45.362 * Node hard reset, now I'm a5dbd72815a1875b58a0cc0fd6a52dc0b76735b7
44119:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:59.352 # configEpoch set to 2 via CLUSTER SET-CONFIG-EPOCH
```

Server 003 logs:

```
44033:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:50.695 # configEpoch set to 0 via CLUSTER RESET HARD
44033:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:50.695 * Node hard reset, now I'm 14d39c0876a982cadd50f301a3d35715171279c0
44033:M 02 Nov 2020 13:30:59.346 # configEpoch set to 3 via CLUSTER SET-CONFIG-EPOCH
```

Am missing something on the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the Redis Cluster port is not accessible on the EC2 instances.

From the [Redis Cluster Specification](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec):

> Every Redis Cluster node has an additional TCP port for receiving incoming connections from other Redis Cluster nodes. This port is at a fixed offset from the normal TCP port used to receive incoming connections from clients. To obtain the Redis Cluster port, 10000 should be added to the normal commands port. For example, if a Redis node is listening for client connections on port 6379, the Cluster bus port 16379 will also be opened.

Comment: that's true! we forgot to open 16379 so the cluster weren't add just because of that